# NSFetchedResultsController wrong sections number

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, sections

My steps are:

1. Push TVC.
2. Init new FRC with Managed Object Context.
3. Perform fetch.
4. Got two sections with one row in each section.
5. Execute fetch request used in FRC.
6. Got array with two elements.
7. Delete last row and save MOC.
8. Pop TVC.
9. Push TVC.
10. Init new FRC with same MOC.
11. Perform fetch.
12. Got TWO sections.
13. Execute fetch request used in FRC.
14. Got array with ONE element.

I tried to call deleteCacheWithName before performing a fetch without success.

I do not understand what to do.

Crash log:

```
2013-01-10 12:27:47.948 MyApp[59830:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'
```

Line of code where app crashes:

```
Card *card = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Here is the CoreDataTableViewController.m from Stanford courses:

```
//
//  CoreDataTableViewController.m
//
//  Created for Stanford CS193p Fall 2011.
//  Copyright 2011 Stanford University. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CoreDataTableViewController.h"

@interface CoreDataTableViewController()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL beganUpdates;

@end

@implementation CoreDataTableViewController

#pragma mark - Fetching

- (void)performFetch {
    if (self.fetchedResultsController) {
        NSLog(@"TVC: Perform fetch");

        NSError *error;
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);

        NSLog(@"TVC: Number of fetched objects in FRC: %d", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count);
        NSLog(@"TVC: Number of sections in FRC: %d", self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)setFetchedResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)newfrc {
    NSFetchedResultsController *oldfrc = _fetchedResultsController;
    if (newfrc != oldfrc) {
        _fetchedResultsController = newfrc;
        newfrc.delegate = self;
        if ((!self.title || [self.title isEqualToString:oldfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name]) && (!self.navigationController || !self.navigationItem.title)) {
            self.title = newfrc.fetchRequest.entity.name;
        }
        if (newfrc) {
            [self performFetch];
        } else {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSUInteger numberOfSections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
    NSLog(@"TVC: DataSource, number of sections: %d", numberOfSections);

    return numberOfSections;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections;
    if (sections.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"TVC: DataSource, there are no sections");
        return 0;
    }

    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];
    NSUInteger numberOfRows = sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
    NSLog(@"TVC: DataSource, number of rows: %d, in section: %d", numberOfRows, section);

    return numberOfRows;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles];
}

#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        self.beganUpdates = YES;
    }
}
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    if (self.beganUpdates)
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
- (void)endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges {
    _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = NO;
}
- (void)setSuspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext:(BOOL)suspend {
    if (suspend) {
        _suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext = YES;
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(endSuspensionOfUpdatesDueToContextChanges) withObject:0 afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void)logFetchedSections:(NSArray *)sections {
}

@end
```

Here is part of my Model:

```
//
//  TLModel.m
//

...

@property (nonatomic, strong) TLCoreData *coreData;

...


- (void)setupFetchedResultsControllerCardsListWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSFetchedResultsController *result))completion {
    [self.coreData performWithDocument:^(UIManagedDocument *document) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Card"];
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"named"
                                                                                         ascending:YES
                                                                                          selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *matches = [document.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Model: Execute fetch request, array count: %d", matches.count);

        NSFetchedResultsController *result = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                 managedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext
                                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath:@"named"
                                                                                            cacheName:nil];
        NSLog(@"Model: Created new FRC: %@", result);

        completion(result);
    }];
}

...
```

Here is TVC:

```
//
//  TLMyTableViewController.m
//

...


- (void)prepareFetchedResultController {
    [self.model setupFetchedResultsControllerCardsListWithCompletion:^(NSFetchedResultsController *result){
        self.fetchedResultsController = result;
    }];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"My Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Card *card = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = card.number;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = card.option;

    return cell;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"TVC: Did load: %@", self);
    [self prepareFetchedResultController];
}

...
```

TLCoreData:

```
//
//  TLCoreData.m
//

#import "TLCoreData.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "TLManagedDocument.h"

@interface TLCoreData()

@property (nonatomic, strong) TLManagedDocument *document;

@end

@implementation TLCoreData

/*
static TLCoreData *_sharedInstance;

+ (TLCoreData *)sharedDocumentHandler {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}
*/

- (TLManagedDocument *)document {
    if (!_document) {
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataUsage.db"];
        _document = [[TLManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    }

    return _document;
}

- (void)performWithDocument:(OnDocumentReady)onDocumentReady {
    void (^OnDocumentDidLoad)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL success) {
        if(success) {
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"Current context: %@", self.document.managedObjectContext);
#endif
            onDocumentReady(self.document);
        }
#ifdef DEBUG
        else
            NSLog(@"Core Data: Managed document does not ready");
#endif
    };

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.document.fileURL path]]) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Core Data: Initialized document: %@", self.document.fileURL);
#endif
        [self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL
                forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
               completionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];
    } else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Core Data: Opened document: %@", self.document.fileURL);
#endif
        [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:OnDocumentDidLoad];
    } else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) {
        OnDocumentDidLoad(YES);
    }
}

- (void)objectsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"Core Data: Objects changed in context: %@", self.document.managedObjectContext);
#endif
}
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"Core Data: Context saved: %@", self.document.managedObjectContext);
#endif
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        // Set our document up for automatic migrations
        NSDictionary *options = @{
            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
        };
        self.document.persistentStoreOptions = options;

        // Register for notifications
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(objectsDidChange:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:self.document.managedObjectContext];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:self.document.managedObjectContext];
    }

    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                  object:self.document.managedObjectContext];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:self.document.managedObjectContext];
}

@end
```

Logs are:

```
2013-01-10 12:27:43.291 MyApp[59830:c07] App: Launched
2013-01-10 12:27:43.354 MyApp[59830:c07] Core Data: Opened document: file://localhost/Users/itsme/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/998028DF-FACC-4EFF-A5C7-B286B91F1100/Documents/DataUsage.db/
2013-01-10 12:27:43.354 MyApp[59830:c07] Model: Logging started
2013-01-10 12:27:43.357 MyApp[59830:c07] App: Did become active
2013-01-10 12:27:43.371 MyApp[59830:c07] Current context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8185590>
2013-01-10 12:27:43.374 MyApp[59830:c07] Current context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8185590>
2013-01-10 12:27:44.746 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Did load: <TLMyTableViewController: 0x8566100>
2013-01-10 12:27:44.746 MyApp[59830:c07] Current context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8185590>
2013-01-10 12:27:44.747 MyApp[59830:c07] Model: Execute fetch request, array count: 2
2013-01-10 12:27:44.748 MyApp[59830:c07] Model: Created new FRC: <NSFetchedResultsController: 0x747bbb0>
2013-01-10 12:27:44.748 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Perform fetch
2013-01-10 12:27:44.750 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Number of fetched objects in FRC: 2
2013-01-10 12:27:44.750 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Number of sections in FRC: 2
2013-01-10 12:27:44.751 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of sections: 2
2013-01-10 12:27:44.752 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of rows: 1, in section: 1
2013-01-10 12:27:44.752 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of rows: 1, in section: 0
2013-01-10 12:27:46.346 MyApp[59830:c07] Current context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8185590>
2013-01-10 12:27:46.347 MyApp[59830:c07] Model: Deleting a row
2013-01-10 12:27:46.349 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of sections: 1
2013-01-10 12:27:46.349 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of sections: 1
2013-01-10 12:27:46.349 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of rows: 1, in section: 0
2013-01-10 12:27:46.350 MyApp[59830:c07] Core Data: Objects changed in context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8185590>
2013-01-10 12:27:46.351 MyApp[59830:c07] Core Data: Context saved: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8185590>
2013-01-10 12:27:47.941 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Did load: <TLMyTableViewController: 0x747d5e0>
2013-01-10 12:27:47.941 MyApp[59830:c07] Current context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8185590>
2013-01-10 12:27:47.942 MyApp[59830:c07] Model: Execute fetch request, array count: 1
2013-01-10 12:27:47.942 MyApp[59830:c07] Model: Created new FRC: <NSFetchedResultsController: 0x74b9410>
2013-01-10 12:27:47.942 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Perform fetch
2013-01-10 12:27:47.944 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Number of fetched objects in FRC: 1
2013-01-10 12:27:47.944 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Number of sections in FRC: 2
2013-01-10 12:27:47.944 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of sections: 2
2013-01-10 12:27:47.945 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of rows: 1, in section: 1
2013-01-10 12:27:47.945 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: DataSource, number of rows: 1, in section: 0
2013-01-10 12:27:47.948 MyApp[59830:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (1) beyond bounds (1)'
```

This line says about wrong number of sections in an array:

```
2013-01-10 12:27:47.944 MyApp[59830:c07] TVC: Number of sections in FRC: 2
```

Source code of this log:

```
NSLog(@"TVC: Number of sections in FRC: %d", self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count);
```

Comment: Provide some code please.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify sources, wait, please

Comment: Try also with the solution I wrote. Thanks.

Comment: Could you remove the logs, leaving only the crash you receive? Thanks.

Comment: I moved whole log to the end and left only crash line

Comment: I added an edit for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide other details for us.

In the meantime I really suggest to take a look at [`NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) class. You can find the method you need to implement in the class reference.

If you set the delegate for your `NSFetchedResultsController` instance like

```
_fetchedController.delegate = self;
```

then, the delegate will respond to changes made to the Core Data model (add or delete sections; add, delete, move or update rows).

For example, if you implement

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
    atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

and you remove or add a section, changes will be captured for you.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

My guess is that if `TLMyTableViewController` extends `CoreDataTableViewController`, you are not calling the right method in

```
- (void)prepareFetchedResultController {
    [self.model setupFetchedResultsControllerCardsListWithCompletion:^(NSFetchedResultsController *result){
        self.fetchedResultsController = result;
    }];
}
```

try to use instead

```
[self setFetchedResultsController:result];
```

Comment: I set delegate in the FRC's setter and it calls didChangeSection method.
Everything works fine in edited TVC.
Then I pop edited TVC and push new one with new FRC (but initialized with same MOC).
And the new TVC can't display itself because FRC give an array with wrong number of sections.

Comment: @cirroz Provide some code. Because it's quite difficult to understand what is going on. Also remove logs and put relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately update didn't help - TVC calls setter in both variations.
Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: I think FRC got some cached results.
I do not understand where it can get them.
FRC is not in consistency state.
One part of FRC returns one fetched record, and it's true, this record lays in one section.
But next part of FRC thinks it still has two sections, but in fact it's not true.

Comment: I do not use cache, I set nil to cache argument when initializing FRC:
    NSFetchedResultsController *result = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                                 managedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext
                                                                                   sectionNameKeyPath:@"named"
                                                                                            cacheName:nil];

Comment: Hi @lorenzo-b, my post has reached one thousand views, said the SO. And I have looked back at it. Now I think I had to call a fetchedresultcontroller's setter explicitly in main queue wrapped in dispatch_async() method. Needs to check it out.